# the Frequencies from the FFT is showing values that it shouldnt

Tags: fft

I'm developing a software to input a monotonic .wav clip (piano) and show the piano notes which are played in that clip. I'm using FFT to calculate the frequencies but they are giving me values such as `22360 Hz` and so on where I want to get around `260 to 600 Hz`.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You need to post some of your code otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Comment: This question is more suited to dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Pianos put out a lot of powerful high harmonics or overtones, and thus an FFT **should** show amplitude in many high frequency bins.  Perhaps you should use a pitch detection or estimation algorithm instead of just an FFT?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you don't have enough samples, so the frequency resolution is poor. All you need to do is to have more samples or just zero-padding. See [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2818/extracting-frequencies-from-fft) and [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/741/why-should-i-zero-pad-a-signal-before-taking-the-fourier-transform). That may help.

Answer (score 0):

Hotpaw2 makes an important point about overtone content.

However another thing you will require is a window function to prevent frequency domain artifacts of the sampling interval from contaminating your result.  The window function applied to the data before the FFT essentially fades the signal in and out smoothly to avoid this.